# What options to mirroring iPad display to Windows 10 PC that balance cost and performance?

Tags: ipad, windows, software-recommendation, mirroring

I would like to record a lecture for my maths students. I want to write it on my iPad, mirror the iPad to my PC laptop, and use OBS on my PC to combine the image of the iPad with the input of my video camera (+ my voice).

I am aware of these methods:

1. Make a zoom call to myself
2. Use LonelyScreen ( not free, works well )
3. Use Apowersoft
4. Use Itools4. ( This is via a USB cable, but unfortunately it lags)

Please comment on the value / performance of your solution. Even though my budget is currently limited, this will be of good use to everyone to cover all options so everyone can shop at their budget to get the best performance at their price point.

Are there better/alternative ways that don't have a lag?

Comment: I’m going to remove the free - clearly anyone with a free solution will trumpet it to the heavens. As you can see, the better designed hardware is not being donated and you can use this hardware to capture massive resolution. iPad resolution and refresh rate just can’t fit through cheap digitizers. Great question - I hope my edit helps you get a great answer or figure how to budget this as well as help everyone else with different budgets.

Answer (score 2):

An iPad can provide HDMI output using an adapter.  You can purchase an HDMI-input adapter (like for capturing game play) for your PC and treat it like any other video input device.

Then use a program that can mix two video input streams.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Could you please tell me what is an HDMI-input adapter, and what kind of program that " can mix two video input streams" should I use?

Comment: @Dmitri Panov Elgato sells video capture hardware and software for Mac and Windows.  https://www.elgato.com/en  I haven't bought hardware from them in a very long time so I don't know anything about their current products.  All I know is that they've done well before and appear to sell products that might fit your needs.

Comment: @DmitriPanov I’ve added some links. Magewell, BlackMagic, Elgato are best of the best and very high value. None are cheap, but you may be very disappointed with $100 or less devices in 2020. In late 2019 you could get great ones for $145 but I don’t expect prices to lower for quality for months to come. In a year, you’ll be back to getting great options. Perhaps in the $89 to $130 space even, but for now, it’s a seller’s market in a huge way.

Comment: OK - I wanted you to get the rep. I’ll make my answer later for you @DmitriPanov  - thanks for reverting if contributed more than you’re comfortable...

Comment: @bmike please write your own answer! Such edits are not edits but rewrites not in my style of writing and I’d prefer to do those myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free app called [LonelyScreen](http://www.lonelyscreen.com/index.html) that will mirror an iPad or iPhone by turning your PC into an AirPlay receiver like a TV (currently a free trial)

I’m not affiliated with the developer and I actually found it by doing a Google search.  I haven’t tested it yet because I don’t have a PC and I was afraid to try boot camp until I started researching it on this site.  But I am going to go for it because this software sounds cool.

I got the instructions from https://www.howtogeek.com/247573/how-to-mirror-your-iphone-or-ipads-screen-on-your-windows-pc/

Comment: According to the website LonelyScreen costs $15 or more per year.

Comment: @nohillside is correct, but I can see where the confusion would come from - the *article* you referenced says free and if you haven’t  downloaded it yet because you haven’t tried it you’d miss the fees.  This is very common though, many companies are switching from “freemium” (meaning free for basic use and you pay for the premium features) to these horrible subscription models.  The article is probably out of date.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try downloading [SMART Notebook Basic for Windows](https://www.smarttech.com/products/education-software/notebook/download/basic), then the [SMART Notebook for iPad](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/smart-notebook-for-ipad/id554245373) app and make sure to download the [SMART Notebook Maestro Add-On](http://go.smarttech.com/notebook-maestro-download) as well.

We use this combo with Macbook Airs/Pros, (not Windows,) and the laptop connects to the iPad, which becomes a virtual whiteboard. I'm not sure if it works with Windows, though. It just might as SMART has gotten much better with multiple OS compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I've followed your links, but for Ipad it tells me concerning "Smart Notebook of iPad" that "This app is currently not available in your country or region". I am based in the UK. Do you think that this means I will not be able to get it? (For windows it worked)

Comment: That's too bad. Try searching specifically in the UK App Store instead of following that link.

Answer (score 0):

The 5KPlayer software (https://www.5kplayer.com) has AirPlay/DLNA support, as well as support for wired connections.

The site looks kind of questionable, but VirusTotal comes back clean for both the [website](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/6e89824ca589046afed61533c5f3b314310c07616fcd76cd2879a81511185bd7/detection) and the [installer file](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/9e772cead6027de31b4961ca955436b490e4eaef4b6b5d1886d752e56e51d8f5/detection), so it should be alright.